# Lock directory except for application

Tags: vb.net, access-control

I'm trying to lock a chosen directory to all users except my application while it's running. I think I need to use the `GetAccessControl` and `SetAccessControl` methods but I haven't been able to use them successfully yet.

Here is the code I'm using for the `GetAccessControl` but I'm getting a design-time error. I'd appreciate any help but I'm pretty new to VB so PLEASE keep it simple.

```
DirectorySecurity.GetAccessControl(FBD1.SelectedPath)
```

Comment: In short: You can't. Users with administrative permission can *always* gain access to a directory on their own computer, if they want to. The StackOverflow community might be able to suggest an alternative workaround that works for your purposes, but for that we need more information. What *exactly* do you want to prevent users from doing and *why*?

Comment: There are ways to make it more difficult for a user to accidently change or delete files (like the TrustedInstaller Windows User ownership for system files) but like Heinzi said there is no way to guarantee single permission. What is your purpose?

Comment: If you want to store just some information or files to which only the app or the user should have control, but the path name isn't important, you should have a look on the "Isolated Storage" concept. If you want to lock a normal random folder, then this is not for you.